# cforms plugin error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am new to wordpress , i am using [cforms II](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/#download) plugin in my site. i am getting following error.

> It seems that your ROOT
>        directory for Wordpress is /green.
>       cforms tried to auto-adjust its
>        settings accordingly, however if you
>       still encounter issues with Ajax (form
>       submission & CAPTCHA reset) please
>        open the file js/cforms.js in your
>        cforms plugin folder and check the
>        sajax_uri variable. (After changing
>       the file, please emtpy your browser
>        cache!)

and when add captcha to my forms, it is not added, not displayed at front side.

why do i get this error .

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the CformsII [FAQ](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-forum/?topic=4&page=1&forum=3) as Oliver has an entire section dedicated to your problem. In short you probably need to check the configuration for your cforms.js and lib_ajax.php file, clear your cache, and restart your browser.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i changed setting in lib_ajax.php, cleared my browser cache and restarted but still getting this error.

Comment: i have one more problem. how to add javascript validation (alert box popup) for my form. do you have any idea please help me.

Comment: I'd follow that FAQ closely, because Oliver covers every thing to a T. If you're still getting that error you may want to post on his forum. As for form validation try the following jQuery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation